# D3.JS: multi-line chart with mouseover tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a multi-series line chart and tried adding tooltips according to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886070/d3-js-multiseries-line-chart-with-mouseover-tooltip) but tooltip is not working and i am not able to figure out what is wrong with my code.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");

var data = [{
  label: "a",
  data: [
    [
      "2016-02-02T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-04T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-06T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-08T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-10T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-12T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-14T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-16T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-18T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-20T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-22T11:34:03Z",
      0.3735178379850471
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-24T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-26T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-28T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-03-01T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ]
  ]
}, {
  label: "b",
  data: [
    [
      "2016-02-02T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-04T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-06T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-08T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-10T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-12T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-14T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-16T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-18T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-20T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-22T11:34:03Z",
      0.25810614839315693
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-24T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-26T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-02-28T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2016-03-01T11:34:03Z",
      0
    ]
  ]
}];


var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(parseDate.parse(d[0]));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  });

var ary = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data);
});

x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));

y.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(c) {
    return d3.min(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  }),
  d3.max(data, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  })
]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "series");

series.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });

series.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) {
    return {
      label: d.label,
      data: d.data[d.data.length - 1]
    };
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(parseDate.parse(d.data[0])) + "," + y(d.data[1]) + ")";
  })
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em");

var mouseG = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
  .attr("class", "mouse-line")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .style("opacity", "0");

var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

mousePerLine.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 7)
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  })
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .style("opacity", "0");

mousePerLine.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
  .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
    d3.select(".mouse-line")
      .style("opacity", "0");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
      .style("opacity", "0");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
      .style("opacity", "0");
  })
  .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
    d3.select(".mouse-line")
      .style("opacity", "1");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
      .style("opacity", "1");
    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
      .style("opacity", "1");
  })
  .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    d3.select(".mouse-line")
      .attr("d", function() {
        var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
        d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
        return d;
      });

    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        console.log(width / mouse[0])
        var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
          bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
            return d[0];
          }).right;
        var idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

        var beginning = 0,
          end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
          target = null;

        while (true) {
          target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
          var pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
          if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
            break;
          }
          if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
          else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
          else break; //position found
        }

        d3.select(this).select('text')
          .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

        return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
      });
  });
```

```css
text.inner-circle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
text.inner-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Metric Regular', 'Metric';
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/6mkcx3mm/)

Please help me in figuring out what mistake i had made and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug comes from the line

```
    var idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);
```

It should be the following instead:

```
    var idx = bisect(d.data, xDate);
```