# d3.js bisector with unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use a bisector graph with unix timestamps and his Answer

[Multiseries line chart with mouseover tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886070/d3-js-multiseries-line-chart-with-mouseover-tooltip)

I am fiddling for some hours now, and don't seem to get why it doesn't work. The bisector always cries about

```
    d3.v3.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

although I am using:

```
      dataset.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = new Date(d.time);
        d.close = +d.close;
      });
```

I have put everything together i a standalone pastebin. Excuse the formatting please. I'd be extremely glad if someone points out the mistake I have done. http://pastebin.com/ycDjYTUW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `bisect` expects an array as a first argument, you are passing it a single value (actually undefined).  I think you meant to just pass `d` to it. Second, in my example you link too, the `lines` array is an array of paths, you've changed it to an array of `g`.

```
var xDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]),
  bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;
  idx = bisect(d, xDate);

var beginning = 0,
  end = lines[i].children[0].getTotalLength(),
  target = null;

...
```

Running code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ddn78VADHEq52etzs8SK?p=preview).