# d3.js mouseover mouseout issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

again I am struggling with d3.js. I have a working Line Chart and partially working mouseover. The goal is to limit the mouseover solely to the svg element, like Mark has it working in his answer [Multiseries line chart with mouseover tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886070/d3-js-multiseries-line-chart-with-mouseover-tooltip)

I have created a Plunker with it. My is-situation is like that.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Jt5jZhnPQy4VpjwY3YBv?p=preview

And I have tried things like:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lRMfa0OiDWEXWYBAjoPd?p=preview
by adding:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
```

But it's always pushing the circles and the bar out of the chart, I am fiddling for some days now and would be extremely glad if someone happens to point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MEtbBqN5qr82yr0CNhUN?p=preview

I simply changed the size of your rectangle:

```
mouseG.append('rect')
.attr("x", margin.left)
.attr("y", margin.top)
.attr('width', w - margin.left - margin.right) 
.attr('height', height - margin.bottom - margin.top)
```

PS: I don't know if you want the line limited to the chart area as well, but if you want, this is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RP4uYKBYnHtX1SvYsLKq?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving width as width :

```
mouseG.append('svg:rect') 
.attr('width', width)
```

do this (give the width of the group same as domain x for the line chart)

```
mouseG.append('svg:rect') 
.attr('width', w - padding * 2)
```

Reason:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([xExtents[0], xExtents[1]])
    .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);
```

Your width of the x scale is `w - padding * 2` so the width of the group listening to the mouse event should be same.

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/icZhK5CnKNTmq42A4phU?p=preview)