# Interactive line-chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to make an interactive line-chart with d3.js. I get the datas from two csv files (emissions.csv and gdp.csv) and I would like that when i pass with the mouse on the graph, it shows a kind of label with information on the corresponding point on the line. Now I have to pass the mouse ON the line to show the label and I can't figure out how to do what i want to do. I've found [this](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/3824661) example that shows what I want but I cant understand some of the code-lines and I can't understand how to use it on mine graph.
Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  /*display: none;*/
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 150},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    //.interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.emission); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("europe_emission.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "year"; }));

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {year: d.year, emission: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));

  y.domain([
    0,
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.emission; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Emission (thousand metric tons of CO2)");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");


              city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.year) + "," + y(d.value.emission) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            //console.log(width/mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.year; }).right;
                idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

            while (true){
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y +")";
          });
      });




});

</script>
```

europe_emission.csv:

year,UnitedKingdom,Italy,France,Spain,Germany
2012,483423,386666,368845,276636,821717
2011,464036,413379,364819,280922,810441
2010,504997,424993,391075,280377,829401
2009,487442,414809,381992,293732,785602
2008,536733,463695,400720,333181,851111
2007,554251,475436,407254,363744,848548
2006,561128,483533,416414,356712,873246
2005,561101,488078,425740,365478,861733
2004,563962,489367,422201,350071,881743
2003,562296,486559,420492,333168,893599
2002,551553,470530,412019,328878,890875
2001,567904,468283,416267,308786,907541
2000,556667,462277,415079,308026,891515
1999,548047,458824,418193,294901,887890
1998,555499,453524,426564,271515,915176
1997,550525,442371,404884,263303,923080
1996,575026,438303,411302,250543,951863
1995,553701,444943,398480,262860,930857
1994,562061,419903,391681,249451,932485
1993,568100,427170,391484,237253,948683
1992,581828,433867,413020,245814,957561
1991,598323,434156,423121,237179,1004735
1990,591499,434656,398769,227508,1042065

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34887578/16363)?

Comment: I've changed the code and the .csv file but it still has a problem and I can't understand why...it looks the same of your answer!..thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me way too long to figure out, but it's your data sorting.  My link above assumed an ascending x axis values, you have descending, so your paths are draw *backwards* right to left.  Either sort your data, or change the search function to go right to left:

```
      d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {

          var beginning = 0,
            end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
            target = null;

          while (true) {
            target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
            pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
            if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
              break;
            }
            if (pos.x > mouse[0]) beginning = target; //<-- this was end = target
            else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) end = target; //<-- this was beginning = target
            else break;
          }

          d3.select(this).select('text')
            .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

          return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
        });
```

Fixed code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/819nUOzwnR3nTEd6uSUK?p=preview).