# how do I have a line follow the mouse on hover, but also have zoom in chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart with zoom. I want to add a vertical line that will follow the mouse along the graph, and display the values at the point for all the lines of the graph.
Found an example [d3.js v4, how do I have a line follow the mouse on hover, but also have a circle follow the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513688/d3-js-v4-how-do-i-have-a-line-follow-the-mouse-on-hover-but-also-have-a-circle)

But when combining with my chart the following problems:

- the line flickers or fades while moving the mouse
- the zoom does not work with the mouse wheel (only works when the
  mouse is in motion)

I understand that the problem is likely that when the cursor moves, it pulls a line, and is called `mouseleave` event for the `zoom` element.
I tried to move the line several pixels to the left or to the right, but this is not what I want, and it still does not work correctly.

I tried to create a line not in the `mouseG` element, as in the example, but on my own `zoom` element. The line is no longer displayed at all.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zkdxrtuc/8/

Comment: all the axis also contain `path` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `line` group below the `zoom` `rect`.

Add second mouse event handlers to the `zoom` `rect`.

To show a line set opacity to 1, to hide set opacity to 0.

```
var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .call(zoom);

function brushed() {
//...
}

function zoomed() {
//...
}

mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

// var lines = focus.selectAll('path');

// var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
//       .data(d3.range(lines.length))
//       .enter()
//       .append("g")
//       .attr("class", "mouse-per-line")
//       .attr('pointer-events', 'none');

// // the circle
// mousePerLine.append("circle")
//   .attr("r", 7)
//   .style("stroke", function(d) { return 'red'; })
//   .style("fill", "none")
//   .style("stroke-width", "1px")
//   .style("opacity", "0");

function showLine(){
  d3.select(".mouse-line").style("opacity", "1");
}
function hideLine(){
  d3.select(".mouse-line").style("opacity", "0");
}

svg.select(".zoom")
  .on('mouseenter.line', showLine)
  .on('mouseleave.line', hideLine)
  .on('mousemove.line', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    //showLine();
    // move the vertical line
    d3.select(".mouse-line")
      .attr("d", function() {
        var d = "M" + (mouse[0] + margin.left) + "," + (height + margin.top);
        d += " " + (mouse[0] + margin.left) + "," + margin.top;
        return d;
      });
    // position the circle and text
  });
```

Comment: It was enough put the `line` group below the `zoom` and change method to set opacity. Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/zkdxrtuc/9/