# Issue with tooltip on d3 line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

So I am trying to implement a tool tip for my line chart using Mark's answer/example from here [Multiseries line chart with mouseover tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886070/multiseries-line-chart-with-mouseover-tooltip)

I'm able to get the tooltip line appear as I hover over my data points however I'm blocked by an error in I assume my x.invert function.

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
> ```

I've checked to see if this is supported d3v4 and researched other examples but no luck.

in my Here is my full code in jsfiddle, thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/zos5jfzp/

Comment: You might want to shorten your code. It's hard to navigate through it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` comes from you name your scale `xScale` and not `x`

You have the same problem for your `y` scale, rename it to `yScale`

You try to get all lines with a query selector on `line` but you didn't assign a class to lines.

```
vis.append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'graph-line')
    .attr('d', lineGen(d.values))
    .style("stroke", function() {
        return d.color = color(d.key);
    })
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr("id", 'tag' + d.key.replace(/[^\w]|_/g, ''))
    .attr('fill', 'none');
```

And

```
var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('graph-line');
```

Finally, you have to change

```
idx = bisect(d.Count, xDate);
```

to

```
idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zos5jfzp/1/